# OpenCart adding form to admin page

Tags: php, opencart

opencart 1.5.6

experimenting with added a page to admin side to upload images to a new folder (for use in other parts of site)

I have a problem in that after the image is uploaded from the form the page redirected to the admin home page. I tried to fix this by re-rendering the current page in the form response, but now I just load a version of the page with no updates and the function doesn't seem to run:

template file: (hello.tpl)

```
<?php echo $header; ?>
<div id="content">
  <div class="breadcrumb">
    <?php foreach ($breadcrumbs as $breadcrumb) { ?>
    <?php echo $breadcrumb['separator']; ?><a href="<?php echo $breadcrumb['href']; ?>"><?php echo $breadcrumb['text']; ?></a>
    <?php } ?>
  </div>

<form action="index.php?route=common/helloworld&token=<?php echo $token; ?>"     method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<?php
if ($error > 0)
{
echo $error;
}
elseif ($error1 > 0)
{
echo $error;
}
elseif ($error2 > 0)
{
echo $error;
}
elseif ($up > 0)
{
echo $up;
echo $type;
echo $size;
echo $store;
echo $store2;
}
else
{
echo "Upload File";
}

?>
</div> 
<?php echo $footer; ?>
```

controller file (hellowworld.php - I know :P I DID say I am experimenting)

```
<?php
class ControllerCommonHelloworld extends Controller { 
    public function index(){
                // VARS

        $this->language->load('common/hello');

                $template="common/hello.tpl"; // .tpl location and file
        $this->load->model('common/hello');
        $this->template = ''.$template.'';
        $this->children = array(
            'common/header',
            'common/footer'
        );      

        $this->data['token'] = $this->session->data['token'];

        $this->data['breadcrumbs'] = array();

        $this->data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'text'      => $this->language->get('text_home'),
            'href'      => $this->url->link('common/home', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL'),
            'separator' => false
        );

        $this->data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'text'      => $this->language->get('heading_title'),
            'href'      => $this->url->link('common/helloworld', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL'),
            'separator' => ' :: '
        );  

        $this->data['error'] = 0;
        $this->data['error1'] = 0;
        $this->data['error2'] = 0;
        $this->data['up'] = 0;

        $this->response->setOutput($this->render());
    }

    public function image ($file) {
    $allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
  {
    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
  {
  $this->data['error'] = "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
      }
else
  {
  $this->data['up'] = "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
  $this->data['type'] = "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
  $this->data['size'] = "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
  $this->data['store'] = "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];

  if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      $this->data['error1'] = $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "../upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      $this->data['store2'] = "Moved To: " . "../upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
      }
    }
  }
else
  {
  $this->data['error2'] = "Invalid file";
  }


    $template="common/hello.tpl"; // .tpl location and file
        $this->load->model('common/hello');
        $this->template = ''.$template.'';
        $this->children = array(
            'common/header',
            'common/footer'
        );      

        $this->data['token'] = $this->session->data['token'];

        $this->data['breadcrumbs'] = array();

        $this->data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'text'      => $this->language->get('text_home'),
            'href'      => $this->url->link('common/home', 'token=' . $this- >session->data['token'], 'SSL'),
            'separator' => false
        );

        $this->data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'text'      => $this->language->get('heading_title'),
            'href'      => $this->url->link('common/helloworld', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL'),
            'separator' => ' :: '
        );
    $this->response->setOutput($this->render());
}
}
?>
```

as I said I am new and experimenting with this software and have never used PHP MVC before.
any pointers would be appriciated!

**SOLVED:**

CONTROLLER:

```
<?php
class ControllerCommonHelloworld extends Controller { 
    public function index(){
                     .................

    public function image() {

        $this->language->load('common/hello');
        $template="common/hello.tpl"; // .tpl location and file
        $this->load->model('common/hello');
        $this->template = ''.$template.'';
        $this->children = array(
            'common/header',
            'common/footer'
        );      

        $this->data['token'] = $this->session->data['token'];

        $this->data['breadcrumbs'] = array();

        $this->data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'text'      => $this->language->get('text_home'),
            'href'      => $this->url->link('common/home', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL'),
            'separator' => false
        );

        $this->data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'text'      => $this->language->get('heading_title'),
            'href'      => $this->url->link('common/helloworld', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL'),
            'separator' => ' :: '
        );

$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 200000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
  {
    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
  {
  $this->data['error'] = "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
  }
else
  {
  $this->data['up'] = "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
  $this->data['type'] = "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
  $this->data['size'] = "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
  $this->data['store'] = "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];

  if (file_exists("/image/TEST/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      $this->data['error1'] = $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "/image/TEST/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      $this->data['store2'] = "Moved To: " . "image/TEST/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
      }
    }
  }
else
  {
  $this->data['error2'] = "Invalid file";
  }


    $this->response->setOutput($this->render());
 }
}
?>
```

TEMPLATE:

```
<?php echo $header; ?>
<div id="content">
  <div class="breadcrumb">
    <?php foreach ($breadcrumbs as $breadcrumb) { ?>
    <?php echo $breadcrumb['separator']; ?><a href="<?php echo $breadcrumb['href']; ?>"><?php echo $breadcrumb['text']; ?></a>
    <?php } ?>
  </div>

<form action="index.php?route=common/helloworld/image&token=<?php echo $token; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<?php
if (isset($error))
{
echo $error;
}

if (isset($error1))
{
echo $error1;
}

if (isset($error2))
{
echo $error2;
}

if (isset($up))
{
echo $up;
echo $type;
echo $size;
echo $store;
echo $store2;
}

if (!isset($error) and !isset($error1) and !isset($error2) and !isset($up))
{
echo "Upload File";
}

?>
</div> 
<?php echo $footer; ?>
```

Comment: update:

ok.. so after some minor changes I appear to have got closer to a solution...

I believe the problem arises at the point the form in submitted, I am not entirely sure the function on the other end is receiving anything from the form

Comment: Before (learning) writing an OpenCart modules/extensions, please, learn PHP first. It's 2013 and Your code looks like from 1995 (+5 yrs because You used the code from existing controller)... This is not meant to offend You but to advise You - OpenCart is written in it's way - but the code is very readable and clean & pretty - the one You have produced makes me wondering where does people today learn the PHP from (possible answer: from the sources/articles/books written before the year 1995).

Answer (score 0):

In your controller you should be building all the standard methods used by OpenCart for form posts such as:

`public function insert()`

`public function update()`

`public function getForm()`

etc.

Take a look at `admin/controller/catalog/attribute.php`

You'll see there's a public method called `insert()` which catches your post data via the `$request` object, ie: `if (($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') && $this->validateForm()) {` all the code inside is executed only if the condition is met, then the method forwards you to `$this->getForm()` which is where your page is rendered.

I'm not sure where you got that example code that you started with but it's not correct, or at least, not in line with the normal OpenCart standards.

Use the existing code in a different file to base your new Modules on.